# Iframe on cordova app not working

Tags: html, cordova, iframe

I am trying to create a hybrid app with an iframe.  The frames are showing in web but in app, the frames did not load.

Should I be using a specific plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to white list the navigation inside the frame.

add this to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="urls you navigate" />
```